# BulkInsert with child entity use of efcore.bulkextensions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have the following code written to insert records Product basic info along with attributes:

```
foreach (var item in records)
                {

                    var productList = new ProductsList()
                    {
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        ItemGroup = item.ItemGroup,
                        ItemType = item.itemType,
                        LegalEntitiesId = legalEntityId,
                        PostedToOtherSys = false,
                        ProductName = item.prodName,
                        ProductNumber = item.prodid,
                        UOM = item.UOM,
                    };

                    foreach (var attribute in item.attributes)
                    {
                        var productListAttributeValues = new ProductListAttributeValues()
                        {
                            CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                            Name = attribute.Name,
                            Value = attribute.type
                        };
                        productList.ProductListAttributeValues.Add(productListAttributeValues);
                    }

                    _unitOfWork.productsListRepository.Add(productList);
                    _unitOfWork.Save();
                }
            }
```

I'm using efcore.bulkextensions library, but I didn't get the how-to insert the base and child entity when a Foreign key relationships exist based on documentation:

[Documentaion](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions)

I tried the follwing:

```
_unitOfWork.productsListRepository.BulkAdd(listOfProducts);
                
                foreach (var entity in listOfProducts)
                {
                    foreach (var subEntity in entity.ProductListAttributeValues)
                    {
                        subEntity.ProductsListId = entity.Id; // setting FK to match its linked PK that was generated in DB
                        listOfProductsAttributes.Add(subEntity);
                    }
                    _unitOfWork.productListAttributeValuesRepository.AddRange(entity.ProductListAttributeValues.ToList());
                }
                _unitOfWork.productListAttributeValuesRepository.BulkAdd(listOfProductsAttributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to add **BulkConfig** options to your underlying `dbContext.BulkInsert` call like this:

`_context.BulkInsert(, new BulkConfig { IncludeGraph = true });`